# replace value from smaller vector to bigger vector

Tags: r

I have a vector with a random set of 100 values, 1:20,  "testing01", and a set of different 20 values "testing02".

now i want to change the values in "testing01" into "testing02", by rule presented in "ff" 
so all "1" in testing01 turns into "2" 
   all "2" in testing01 turns into "16" (according to my sample()in "testing02")

i will use the new vector to recreate a matrix "testing04" to update "testing03"

```
testing01 <- as.vector(matrix(sample(1:20), 10,10))
testing02 <- c(sample(20,20))
testing03 <-matrix(testing01,10,10)
ff<- rbind(seq(unique(testing01)),testing02)
```

how can I replace the values?

---

It happened that the problem i wanted to solve was a bit different than the first example i gave. please allow me to update the example (i leave the old one in case it would be useful for someone else :))

```
t1 <-c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,
22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,36,37,40,41,42,44,45,46,
47,48,50,51,57,61,62)

t2 <-c(0,1,3,2,5,4,7,6,9,8,11,11,12,13,14,15,16,16,18,18,20,21,23,22,
24,24,26,26,28,28,31,31,32,32,34,36,37,41,40,42,44,45,46,47,49,51,
51,57,60,63)
newrule <-rbind(t1,t2)
set.seed(24)
t3 <- c(matrix(sample(t1),10,10))
```

The goal is to update "t3" by changing "t1" values using "t2" values, creating a new vector "t4" (so all 2 turns to 3,10 turns to 11, 11 remains 11, 16 remains 16..and so on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
unname(setNames(ff[2,], ff[1,])[testing01])
```

#### Update

May be this helps

```
v1 <- unname(setNames(newrule[1,], newrule[2,])[as.character(t3)])
ifelse(is.na(v1), t3, v1)
```

Or

```
colSums(rbind(v1,is.na(v1)*t3), na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi, would unname(setNames()) work the same for a vector containing for example 1:20, but missing 13, 17,19 (so in total 17 values)? I am trying a vector of length 288 from value ranging from 1:511 but i got a lot of NA values and had disappearing values. (i try to fit it into vector containing 10,000 values, but the result had only 1,376 values with a lot of NA)

Comment: @KTWU In the example you provided, `ff` has a unique key/value pair.  But in the case you mentioned in the comments, the lengths differ (ie. 288 vs. 17).  It would be helpful if you update the post with a new example

Comment: @9StoriesAround  I would suggest you to post as a new question as this is a bit different question, but you can edit your post with a new example and expected result

Comment: now all rules followed, i'll try to ask a new question, thanks!